# Archos 80 Xenon debugging issue

Tags: android, debugging, archos

I am having problem debugging my application on this tablet.

I have tried to update my sdk, but it made no difference.

I enabled the debugging mode on the tablet.

My problem is that i do not see my device on the eclipse device picker.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Archos devices have a strange way of enabling ADB drivers. I'd recommend you follow tutorials on ArchosLounge (FR) or on Archosfans (EN) forums.

Basically, it's just that you have to instll PDANet at first for drivers then modify them and edit other files (on Windows, lines to add on .inf files)

I'll edit if I find the links.

EDIT : [It might be more simple now](http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html?country=gb&lang=en)

Comment: I have been in this site, and seriously i have not understand what am i suppose to do, i downloaded the zip file, now what should i do?
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ok so i found out how to update my adb, but windows says that my adb is up to date.

i have no more ideas..

Comment: I tried to restart the Eclipse (after shutting down the adb from task manager) and this message came up:

An internal error occurred during: "Start Ruble bundle manager".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 1. The drivers have to be updated on top of the existing. That's why it's recommended to install PDANet and its drivers first. 
2. Please open a new question, I think this is more of an Eclipse issue (NPE)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about the first thing you said? what is this pdanet? and how can i update my adb on top of my exciting?